# Categories, whose objects are morphisms

Tags: category-theory

I am interested in categories, whose objects are morphisms (in an other category).

I want to see examples of such categories.

I have examples of this in my research: Such as the categories of continuous functions between endo-funcoids (or endo-reloids). Endo-funcoids (and endo-reloids) are themselves morphisms in respective categories, but they are connected with "continuous function" morphisms.

Comment: Sorry but... what is the question being asked?

Comment: I added the question: "I want to see examples of such categories."

Answer (score 4):

Every example comes from a 2-category. All natural examples probably come from natural examples of 2-categories, such as $\mathbf{Cat}$, the 2-category of all small categories (and functors and natural transformations). A more interesting example might be the 2-category of rings, bimodules, and bimodule homomorphisms. I.e. $\hom(R,S)$ is the category of all $(R,S)$-bimodules, and composition of bimodules is given by the tensor product), so the objects of the category $R-\mathbf{Mod}-S$ are the (1-)morphisms in the category I described.

Comment: Can you prove that "every example comes from a 2-category"?

Comment: @porton: In fact, every category is a hom-category in a 2-category. It's pretty much the same as the proof that every monoid is a hom-set in a category. Actually it's more like the more trivial proof that every set is a hom-set in a category: just define a 2-category with objects $X$ and $Y$, and $\hom(X,Y)$ to be whatever category you like. (and all other hom-categories empty or trivial as appropriate)